# JMF mp3 plugin error

Tags: java

Hello guys I am trying to develop mp3 player in java . I hava installed jmf and also included 
jmfmp3plugin and here is my code..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SoundPlayer extends JFrame{
    public void plmusic(){
        try {
            Clip clp = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("1_welcome.wav"));
            clp.open(is);
            FloatControl fc =(FloatControl) clp.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            fc.setValue(-50f);
            clp.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File f = new File("love_is_gone.mp3");
            MediaLocator ml;
            ml = new MediaLocator(f.toURL());
            Player p;
            p = Manager.createPlayer(ml);
            p.start();
        } catch (NoPlayerException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

But I am getting this error

> Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo,
>   LittleEndian, Signed, 16000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits Failed
>   to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@7129a843 Error: Unable to
>   realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@7129a843

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html mp3 seems not to be supported? Ah, sorry, you are using the mp3 -plugin.